# Exporting Adobe Illustrator (AI) file layer from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, illustrator

How do I export Adobe Illustrator (AI) layers from QGIS?

I have tried all the "save as" files from layer and non of them worked.

Comment: either export to dxf or svg in QGIS to use in Adobe Illustrator. Improvements with layering and pdf export is coming with v3.x

Comment: @Mapperz Any idea when will v3.x be released?

Comment: When the development team is happy with a stable release.

Comment: 52% complete https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/roadmap#Version_3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Mapperz suggested, you can save a layer as a DXF from QGIS. The DXF can be imported into Illustrator easily enough, though you may have issues with scaling.

[image]

However, as Illustrator drawings are often set up as standard pages, it's probably better to create a print composer and save the page as either an SVG or a PDF.

[image]

If you're interested in purchasing a 3rd party program, I've used **[MaPublisher](http://www.avenza.com/mapublisher)** by Avenza before, and it's pretty good. It can import standard [**GIS files**](http://www.avenza.com/mapublisher/features/supported-formats) directly into Illustrator.